# Convert Ajax submit form then get HTML response to Pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

```
//THIS AJAX CODE WORKING GREAT.
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#ajaxupload").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            url: "http://example.com/upload",
            type: "POST",
            data:  new FormData(this),
            mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data){
            //if success. Response is HTML. data = html. insert to my .result-wrapper.
            $(".result-wrapper").prepend(data);
            },
            error: function(){
               console.log('there\'s error!')
            }
       });
    }));
});
```

How to convert this **Ajax Jquery** to pure Javascript? I've try to find solution around Stackoverflow then try to implement codes by answer was mark as accepted still error, my backend Controller not detect the data input value..

With ajax codes above.
 1. Sumbit and get response without refresh the page.

2. Response is HTML.
3. No need to set data. because data already  set in my HTML form.
4. Form have multiple input file upload and multiple input name. So length of input not a static number, depend files.

How to implement it with javascript? Submit without refresh, get response, then possible to submit data filled in HTML dinamically?

I've try do that with code below.

```
document.getElementById('ajaxupload').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      //e.submit();
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', 'http://example.com/upload/', true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      xhr.onload = function () {
         // do something to response
         console.log(this.responseText);
      };
      //xhr.send();
      xhr.send(document.getElementById('ajaxupload').innerHTML); //my form id = ajaxupload
   });
```

HTML:

```
<form action="http://example.com/upload" id="ajaxupload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
<input id="insert-file" name="usr_files[]" type="file" multiple="">
<!--other input will generate inside this form on change `insert-file` .. depend on how many length file selected. ex if 2 files selected: 
<input class="custom-file-name" name="usr_files[text][0]" type="text" value="My custom file name" required/>
<input class="custom-file-name" name="usr_files[text][1]" type="text" value="My custom file name no.2" required/> -->
</form>
```

Comment: Why would you think sending the entire HTML of the form is anywhere near the same as sending a FormData object? FYI: `XMLHttpRequest` supports FormData as well *(in modern browsers)*

Comment: so that's mean my javascript code above will working if I set data? how to implement it with multiple file select?

Comment: `xhr.send(document.getElementById('ajaxupload').innerHTML)` wat

Comment: yes @Kevin B, I'm noob in pure javascript that's why I'm asking. document.getElementById('ajaxupload').innerHTML just example to explain that I want to get all data inside form without set it by collect data from input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same formdata object in the native code

```
document.getElementById('ajaxupload').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var formData = new FormData(this);
  var xhr      = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open('POST', 'http://example.com/upload/');

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if ( xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200 ) {
           console.log( xhr.responseText );
       }
  }

  xhr.send( formData ); //my form id = ajaxupload
});
```

Comment: Thank you @adeneo, it's working and this new codes become more simple than my ajax(jquery) codes before this.

Answer (score -1):

```
function ajaxGet(url, cb, token){
```

var ajaxReq = new XMLHttpRequest();

ajaxReq.addEventListener('load', function(){

if(ajaxReq.status === 200) cb(null, {responseText: ajaxReq.responseText, rawAjaxRequest: ajaxReq});

else cb({statusCode: ajaxReq.status, rawAjaxRequest: ajaxReq}, null);

});

ajaxReq.addEventListener('error', function(data){

console.dir(data);

var err = new Error('A fatal error occurred during ajaxGet, see console for more information');

err.name = 'XMLHttpRequestError';

cb(err, null);

});

ajaxReq.open('GET', url, true);

if(token){

ajaxReq.setRequestHeader('Authorization', token);

}

ajaxReq.send();

},